# Multicolumn with balanced cell width

Tags: multicolumn

I have created a table with uneven mergers of cells:

```
\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|l|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
               & A               & B              & C         & D          & E              & F              \\ \hline
\textsc{baris} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{bar=is}      & bar=o     & bar=u      & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{bar=um}     \\ \hline
\textsc{torun} & tor=un          & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{tor=e} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{tor=us} & tor=um         \\ \hline
…              & …               & …              & …         & …          & …              & …              \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

This is the result:

[image]

As you can see, every second cell of a merged couple has a shorter width. Is there a simple way to make them of the same width?

Thanks to everyone

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|l|*{6}{wc{1cm}|}}
\hline
               & A               & B              & C         & D          & E              & F              \\ \hline
\textsc{baris} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{bar=is}      & bar=o     & bar=u      & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{bar=um}     \\ \hline
\textsc{torun} & tor=un          & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{tor=e} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{tor=us} & tor=um         \\ \hline
…              & …               & …              & …         & …          & …              & …              \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

Like this, i.e. that all columns (except the first) has equal width?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabularx}{0.9\linewidth}{|l|*{6}{C|} }
\hline
               & A               & B              & C         & D          & E              & F              \\ \hline
\textsc{baris} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{bar=is}      & bar=o     & bar=u      & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{bar=um}     \\ \hline
\textsc{torun} & tor=un          & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{tor=e} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{tor=us} & tor=um         \\ \hline
…              & …               & …              & …         & …          & …              & …              \\ \hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

**Addendum:** Some off-topic improvements of table (more vertical spaces around cell contents, use of option for `\schape` text, newcommand for `\multicolumn{2}{c|}{...}`, `...` are replaced with `\dots`):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{makecell, tabularx}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\newcommand\mcc[1]{\multicolumn{2}{c|}{#1}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}
\centering
\setcellgapes{2pt}
\makegapedcells
\begin{tabularx}{0.9\linewidth}{|>{\scshape}l|*{6}{C|} }
    \hline
        & A             & B             & C             & D & E     & F \\ \hline
baris   & \mcc{bar=is}  & bar=o         & bar=u         & \mcc{bar=um}  \\ \hline
torun   & tor=un        & \mcc{tor=e}   & \mcc{tor=us}  & tor=um        \\ \hline
\dots   & \dots         & \dots         & \dots         & \dots     & \dots & \dots \\ 
    \hline
\end{tabularx}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]